# Get current system local encoding in Perl on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, character-encoding, locale

I need to get the current encoding according to the system local settings. I'm looking for such function working this way:

```
my $sysEncoding = getSystemEncoding();
#and now $sysEncoding equals e.g. 'windows-1250'
```

I looked everywhere on the internet. I've found just the module `PerlIO::locale`. But I thing that the system encoding should be recognized easier without additional modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use Win32::API;
if (Win32::API->Import('kernel32', 'int GetACP()')) {
    $enc = GetACP();
    print "Current local encoding is '$enc'\n";
}
```

Thanks for hint to [Ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami).

Answer (score 3):

[Encode::Locale](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode%3a%3aLocale) provides the means to handle this.